# Range('A','Z') jQuery issue

Tags: php, jquery, range

I've got a PHP function that creates a < li > with each letter of the alphabet.

```
<?php foreach(range('A','Z') as $letter) : ?>
<li><input type="button" id="alpha-button" value="<?php echo $letter; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This generates a list with no problems. However, when I try to apply the following function, it only runs with the first button generated.

```
$(function(){
    $("#alpha-button").click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an id selector, and ids need to be unique inside the DOM.

You should change it to use a `class` instead of an `id`, like this:

```
<?php foreach(range('A','Z') as $letter) : ?>
<li><input type="button" class="alpha-button" value="<?php echo $letter; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And the JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".alpha-button").click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have the same id for each `<li>`.

You may change it to

```
<?php foreach(range('A','Z') as $letter) : ?>
<li><input type="button" class="alpha-button" value="<?php echo $letter; ?>"></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $(".alpha-button").click(function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```